# Django table with query results and computed data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to list the last entry a user makes in a table along with the number of entries the user has made. The query I have so far gets me the last entry (there can only be one active at a time)

```
data = Student.objects.filter(session=session, active=True)
```

The objects are then sent over and displayed in a table

```
 {% for item in data %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
  <td align="center">{{ [count here]}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like the count for the number of times the user's name appears in the database in the same row as the object data itself. I would like the count displayed where "count here" is as above.

Student Model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    session = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    contribution_marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timemark = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you add your models to your question

Comment: Student model added

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well:

you have the last data like this:

```
last_active = Student.objects.filter(session=session, active=True).last()
```

and the counter like this:

```
count = Student.objects.filter(session=session).count()
```

so in your template you can use like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ last_active.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ last_active.category }}</td>
  <td align="center">{{ count }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Forgot to add that there are multiple users. How do I get the count to appear in the row that also has the last active object?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
  
</tr>
{% if forloop.last %}
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">{{data.count}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Subquery` to get the total count for each name in the `Student` table and use an `OuterRef` to filter the `Subquery` by the name for each row

```
from django.db.models import Count, Subquery, OuterRef
data = Student.objects.filter(
    session=session,
    active=True
).annotate(
    count=Subquery(
        Student.objects.filter(
            name=OuterRef('name')
        ).values(
            'name'
        ).annotate(
            count=Count('name')
        ).values('count')
    )
)
```

Template

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
  <td align="center">{{ item.count }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```